# Changing value separation from "," to "-" (JS/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I received some Jquery code for an HTML checkbox. Essentially, when checked, the value of the checkbox is placed in an input box. When I uncheck the box, the value is cleared from the input. However, when you check multiple checkboxes, a "," separates the values. **Is there a way to seperate the values by "-" instead of ","?** I tried playing around with the code and it just breaks the code. I am fairly new to JS/Jquery so if it is a simple answer, I apologize. I can provide more information if needed. A working JSFiddle with "," is here: https://jsfiddle.net/m240Laka/25/

My code is located here:

```
 var $choiceDisplay = $("#choiceDisplay"), //jquery selector for the display box
    $none = $("#none"),
    $choice = $(".choice");

$choice.on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this), //jquery selector for the changed input
    isThisChecked = $this.prop("checked"), //boolean true if the box is checked
    choiceSelectionsArray = $choiceDisplay.val().split(",").filter(function(e){return e !== ""}), //array of values that are checked
    isThisValueInDisplayedSelection = $.inArray($this.val(), choiceSelectionsArray) !== -1; //boolean true when $this value displayed

if (isThisChecked) {
    if (isThisValueInDisplayedSelection) {
        return false; //odd, the value is already displayed.  No work to do.
    } else {
        choiceSelectionsArray.push($this.val());
        $choiceDisplay.val(choiceSelectionsArray.join());
    }
} else { //box has been unchecked
    if (isThisValueInDisplayedSelection) {
        choiceSelectionsArray = choiceSelectionsArray.filter(function(e){return e !== $this.val()})
        $choiceDisplay.val(choiceSelectionsArray.join());
    }
}
});

$none.on("change", function () {
   var $this = $(this),
   isThisChecked = $this.prop("checked");
if(isThisChecked){
    $choice.prop({
        disabled: true,
        checked : false
    });
    $choiceDisplay.val("");
}else{
    $choice.prop({disabled: false});
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the functions `join()` and `split()`, you need to pass in the delimiter you want, `'-'`. I suggest creating a local variable that you use, so it is easier to change this if needed.

```
var $choiceDisplay = $("#choiceDisplay"), //jquery selector for the display box
    $none = $("#none"),
    $choice = $(".choice"),
    delimiter = '-';

$choice.on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this), //jquery selector for the changed input
        isThisChecked = $this.prop("checked"), //boolean true if the box is checked
        choiceSelectionsArray = $choiceDisplay.val().split(delimiter).filter(function(e){return e !== ""}), //array of values that are checked
        isThisValueInDisplayedSelection = $.inArray($this.val(), choiceSelectionsArray) !== -1; //boolean true when $this value displayed

    if (isThisChecked) {
        if (isThisValueInDisplayedSelection) {
            return false; //odd, the value is already displayed.  No work to do.
        } else {
            choiceSelectionsArray.push($this.val());
            $choiceDisplay.val(choiceSelectionsArray.join(delimiter));
        }
    } else { //box has been unchecked
        if (isThisValueInDisplayedSelection) {
            choiceSelectionsArray = choiceSelectionsArray.filter(function(e){return e !== $this.val()})
            $choiceDisplay.val(choiceSelectionsArray.join(delimiter));
        }
    }
});
```

Here is it in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m240Laka/29/).

Answer (score 0):

In $.join() add the separator string parameter:

```
$choiceDisplay.val(choiceSelectionsArray.join("-"));
```

UPDATE:

add the same in $.split()

```
choiceSelectionsArray = $choiceDisplay.val().split("-")....
```